# Load Kernel Modules boot error after do-release-upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, kernel, do-release-upgrade

I had a headless box running 14.04

I ran `do-release-upgrade` to 16.04

Now I'm getting an error and failure to boot on the latest kernel but an older kernel boots fine when selected from advanced boot mode. The error is:

`Failed to start Load Kernel Modules
See 'systemctl status systemd-modules-load.service for details`

The boot continues but stops at

`Starting Show Plymouth Boot Screen...`

`systemctl status systemd-modules-load.service` in a secondary terminal does run but does not apear to contain anything specific or useful, to my inexperienced eyes at least.

Any constructive help would be greatly appreciated.

***UPDATE***

Default kernel that fails:

`Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-103-generic`

Alternative kernel that encounters the same error, but eventually boots to a console prompt as expected.

`Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-137-generic`

***UPDATE2***

`cat /lib/systemd/system/systemd-modules-load.service`

```
● systemd-modules-load.service - Load Kernel Modules
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-modules-load.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2017-12-15 15:27:23 AEDT; 32min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-modules-load.service(8)
           man:modules-load.d(5)
 Main PID: 247 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Warning: Journal has been rotated since unit was started. Log output is incomplete or unavailable.
```

`cat /etc/modules-load.d/modules.conf`

```
# /etc/modules: kernel modules to load at boot time.
#
# This file contains the names of kernel modules that should be loaded
# at boot time, one per line. Lines beginning with "#" are ignored.


# Generated by sensors-detect on Wed Apr 13 23:29:38 2016
# Chip drivers
it87
lm63
```

I attempted to comment those two drivers and the situation got worse.

Comment: ,The answer to the question in your title is no. Did you ever get your 16.04 install to work? If so, what is the relevance of the fact that you upgraded? Please provide key info such as the kernel versions that do and do not work.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Thanks for your feedback. Added more info. Perhaps I should also change the question (title) ?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed!

I ran `sensors-detect` and it found I needed `w83627ehf` and added this to my "`/etc/modules`" (in fact, `/etc/modules-load.d/module.conf`) file.

`sensors-detect` suggested I run `/etc/init.d/kmod start` and I did but this failed again as it wasn't able to load `it87` so I commented that out of the `/etc/modules-load.d/modules.conf` file and boom, no more `Load Kernel Modules` error!

Alas I think I've still a little way to go before I can boot in a `4.x` series kernel without that pesky hang (though secondary terminals work fine) on `Starting Show Plymouth Boot Screen...`

Hope this helps someone out in the future.